# pd.series.str.pad() returns NaNs

Tags: python, pandas

`patients_clean.zip_code`
returns:

```
0      92390
1      61812
2      68467
3       7095
4      36303
5      32114
```

I want to pad it so that zip codes with missing '0's on the left are fixed, so I apply this:
`patients_clean.zip_code.str.pad(width=5, side='left', fillchar='0')`

However, this returned a series of NaNs can anyone explain this behaviour?

```
0     NaN
1     NaN
2     NaN
3     NaN
4     NaN
5     NaN
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think values are not strings, but integers, so need [`Series.astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
print (patients_clean.zip_code.astype(str).str.pad(width=5, side='left', fillchar='0'))
0    92390
1    61812
2    68467
3    07095
4    36303
5    32114
Name: zip_code, dtype: object
```

Her working also same way [`Series.str.zfill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.zfill.html):

```
print (patients_clean.zip_code.astype(str).str.zfill(5))
0    92390
1    61812
2    68467
3    07095
4    36303
5    32114
Name: zip_code, dtype: object
```

Comment: actually values were 'object' so I thought it would work, I thought 'object' and 'str' are treated similarly in pandas?

Comment: How good are you with pandas so you answer every possible question?